# Colourized command for grep output

Tags: debian, colors, logging, grep

Hey forum!

I have recently begun working with **Debian** and do so in a purely command-line environment.  I connect from a windows desktop through **puTTY** using asymmetric encryption rather than passwords.

My principle reason for running a Linux server is to allow SFTP access to share files with external users over the internet.  I do this using SSH and a 'chroot jail' which gives me a reasonable degree of inherent security.  Nonetheless I need to be fairly diligent in examining the '*/var/logs/auth.log*' file for intrusion attempts.  Unfortunately I have discovered this holds authentication data for all logins in the Linux system, not just the SSH daemon - which is quite hard to run my eyes over!

In order to narrow the log entries displayed to just those relevant for SFTP reporting I currently use:

```
grep SSHD /var/logs/auth.log | more
```

However, I wondered if there was an alternative to '**more**' that I could pipe '**grep**'s output into that would offer colourization similar to '**vim**/**view**' with ':syntax enable' set?

The closest I have come so far is:

```
grep --color=always SSHD /var/logs/auth.logs | more
```

This gives a red 'SSHD' highlighting in the text string which does indeed help the eyes a *little*.  However it is not so good as the syntax highlighting in '**vim**'.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing external tools, my call would be [**Pygments**](http://pygments.org/)

> It is a generic syntax highlighter for general use in all kinds of
>   software such as forum systems, wikis or other applications that need
>   to prettify source code. Highlights are:
>
> - a wide range of common languages and markup formats is supported
> - special attention is paid to details that increase highlighting
> - quality support for new languages and formats are added easily; most
>     languages use a simple regex-based lexing mechanism
> - a number of output
>     formats is available, among them HTML, RTF, LaTeX and ANSI sequences
> - it is usable as a command-line tool and as a library ...
> - and it
>     highlights even Brainf*ck!

After installing it, you can use it like:

```
pygmentize -g file
```

... and you will get a beautiful colorized output.

---

You can even use it as an alias - put this in your `.profile` file:

```
alias colorseverywhere='pygmentize -g'
```

... and then try running it like (as per your example):

```
grep SSHD /var/logs/auth.log | colorseverywhere
```

... or just:

```
colorseverywhere /var/logs/auth.log
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks Jim - I will give that a look over!  I like the fact it can be used with many different input files.